# How much will upgraded processor and RAM affect battery life?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, battery, processor

I'm considering purchasing a new Macbook Air, and one of my main goals would be to maximize battery life.  If I upgrade the standard processor (from 1.3GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 to 1.7GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i7) or RAM (from 4GB SDRAM to 8GB SDRAM), by how much should I expect battery life to be reduced?  Would it be only when using all of the RAM / processor power?

Comment: This article from Macworld compared the battery life of the stock MBA against the top specced Air, and the times were comparable: http://www.macworld.com/article/2042376/lab-tested-new-macbook-air-offers-best-battery-life-of-any-apple-laptop.html